# Is it better practice to try to pass variables to a function whose names aren't the same as the arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments

So obviously one of the major things a beginner learns is that arguments of a function will stay within that function, so you don't need to worry about overlap between variables. (If they are private.)

In an attempt to have better coding style to help readability and my work within my own code, is it better to actually try to avoid passing a variable into a function with the same name as an argument in the function?

For example:

```
x = 0

def print_out(x_in):
    print x_in
```

instead of

```
x = 0

def print_out(x):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very common. For example:

```
def do_one_day(year, month, day):
    print datetime.date(year, month, day)

def do_the_whole_month(year, month):
    for day in xrange(1, 32): # bug, but you get the idea
        do_one_day(year, month, day)
```

Each variable should have whatever name is best in its context: in this case it makes sense to call the year `year` in both functions, and we don't change that just because one function calls the other.

In your example though, `x` isn't just the name of an argument passed to `print_out`, it's actually in the same scope where `print_out` is defined. Since `print_out` can access `x` directly by name, it's often clearer to give the parameter a different name so as not to hide the outer `x`. Even if you have no intention of using the outer `x` in your function, and even though Python will have no trouble understanding what you mean, someone reading the code might have in mind that there's this global called `x`. They might confuse them, or they might waste a moment trying to work out why they have the same name.

Calling a global `x` is probably a bad idea, anyway. In practice it's pretty rare that a *good* name for a global clashes with a good name for a parameter. The problem might arise in practice for a function defined inside another function:

```
def do_the_next_year(year, month):
    def increment(year, month):
        month += 1
        if month == 13:
            month = 1
            year += 1
        return year, month
    for _ in xrange(12):
        year, month = increment(year, month)
        do_the_whole_month(year, month)
```

Leaving aside whether we really should make `increment` an inner function at all, we ask ourselves, should `increment` use different names for its parameters to avoid confusion with the outer `year` and `month`? In this case it's probably OK, but you have to consider whether your function is readable in context, and whether future changes would involve accessing the outer variables.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. But be aware that the body of a function closes over the outer scope for any variable that is not passed as an argument.

```
x = 0

def foo():
    print(x)
```

The output is `0`.

This is a good thing but must be kept in mind.